# Prevent JS from moving to another page

Tags: javascript

I need to prevent the user from moving to another page after click submit button, the code

```
<div class="form"><div class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="check"> I have read and agree to the <a href="#" target="_blank" class="agree"><b>Copyright Declaration</b></a></div></div>

 <button type="submit" name="add" id="addtocart" class="btn" onclick="if(!this.form.agree.checked){alert('You must agree to the Copyright Declaration.');return false}" >
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the form tag make an attribute called

```
onsubmit="if(!this.form.agree.checked){alert('You must agree to the Copyright Declaration.');return false}"
```

Comment: The correct name is `onsubmit`. HTML tag attribute names follow kebab-case convention.

Comment: better to avoid inline javascript